# How to check equivalence using a loop and then execute some code if there's no equivalence?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I did something like this:

```
for (vector<vector<int> > :: iterator it = result.begin(); it != it.end(); ++it) {
  if (equal(it->begin(), it->end(), triplet->begin()) {
    flag = 1;
    break;
  }
}
if (flag != 1) triplets.insert(triplet);
```

I'm wondering how to do this without a "flag". Thanks.

Comment: Your title says execute `triplets.insert(triplet);` if there is no equivalence, but your code says execute `triplets.insert(triplet);` only if there is equivalence. Did you mean `if (flag != 1)`?

Comment: @jonhopkins tks I just corrected it

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** After the code-change (flag==1 vs flag!=1), this answer is **no longer correct**.

Because you `break` you can just put your code inside the for:

```
for (vector<vector<int> > :: iterator it = result.begin(); it != it.end(); ++it) {
  if (equal(it->begin(), it->end(), triplet->begin()) {
    triplets.insert(triplet);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer only works if the code in the post is correct. As jonhopkins pointed out in his comment, if the OP really meant for that test to be `if (flag != 1)` then this approach will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`std::none_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) function from `<algorithm>`.

```
if (std::none_of(result.begin(), result.end(), [&triplet](const vector<int> &it) -> bool {
    return equal(it.begin(), it.end(), triplet.begin());
}) {
    triplets.insert(triplet);
}
```

This function takes a range and a unary predicate (here I'm using a C++11 lambda), and returns `true` or `false` depending on whether any of the elements in the range return a `true` value from the predicate. There are two other variants `std::any_of()` and `std::all_of()` as well.